# Sending frictionless requests to facebook friends using Android

Tags: android, facebook, apprequests

I just upgraded from facebook sdk 3.23.0 to 4.8.2, and to me it seems like that facebook has taken sending frictionless request on android away.

They have clearly documented how to send frictionless requests on ios and web but havent detailed anything about android.

As per their documentation

> On Android, the option is in the control of the player whether or not they'd like to allow sending requests without a confirmation step. On the Android platform, the game client is unaware of this setting.

Does anyone have an idea where is this control and how can we change it. I tried sending request from the new sdk and i did not see frictionless check box.

Any help or suggestion around this would as to how we can send requests would be really helpful.